# Showing and hiding inputs based on checkboxGroupInput

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

My shiny app begins with a `checkboxGroupInput` which contains the names of three companies: `A`, `B` and `C`. It also has 3 `hidden` numeric inputs, each corresponding to a company. Potential investors may select the name of the company they wish to invest in and specifiy the amount they are willing to invest. When the name of a company is checked, the corresponding numeric input shows up. Also, when the company name is unchecked, the numeric input disappears.

The `checkboxGroupInput` is called `company`. The 3 `numericInput` fields are respectively called `amountA`, `amountB` and `amountC` and are all generated inside a `uiOutput`. They are hidden with the `hidden` function of `shinyjs`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(magrittr)

ui <- fluidPage(

  useShinyjs(),

  checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "company", label = "Select a company", choices = LETTERS[1:3]),

  uiOutput(outputId = "amounts")

)

server <- function(input, output){

  company_names <- LETTERS[1:3]
  num_ids <- paste0("amount", LETTERS[1:3])

  output$amounts <- renderUI({

    num_inputs <- lapply(1:3, function(i){
      numericInput(inputId = num_ids[i], label = paste0("Investment in ", company_names[i]), value = 0, min = 0, max = 5000)
    }) %>% tagList

    shinyjs::hidden(num_inputs)

  })

  observeEvent(eventExpr = input$company, handlerExpr = {

    if(length(input$company) == 0){
      for(i in num_ids){
        shinyjs::hide(id = i)
      }
    } else {
      for(i in input$company){
        shinyjs::toggle(id = paste0("amount", i), condition = input$company)
      }
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The problem with my app is that the intended dynamics between the `checkboxGroupInput` and the `numericInput` fields are not working as intended. For instance, once a `numericInput` is shown, it cannot be hidden anymore by unchecking the boxes. How can I handle this?

The code pasted above is fully functional. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your code by explicitly show/hide the `numericInput` when the corresponding check box is selected/unselected. Also I change the `observeEvent` with `observe` to make sure that the observer reacts when none of the check boxes are selected.

```R
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(magrittr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "company", label = "Select a company", choices = LETTERS[1:3]),
  uiOutput(outputId = "amounts")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  company_names <- LETTERS[1:3]
  num_ids <- paste0("amount", LETTERS[1:3])

  output$amounts <- renderUI({

    num_inputs <- lapply(1:3, function(i){
      numericInput(inputId = num_ids[i], label = paste0("Investment in ", company_names[i]), value = 0, min = 0, max = 5000)
    }) %>% tagList

    shinyjs::hidden(num_inputs)
  })

  observe({
    for(i in company_names){
      if (i %in% input$company) {
        shinyjs::show(id = paste0("amount", i))
      } else {
        shinyjs::hide(id = paste0("amount", i))
      }  
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I inverted the `if` statement and the `for` loop and also, thank you for being explicit about why use `observe` instead of `observeEvent`.